# Trigger Javascript when div in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I'm using the following javascript to check if a div is in view and then triggering an event.

However, it only triggers when the div is at the very TOP of the screen.  How can I get it to trigger as soon as the div is at the CENTER of the screen?

```js
$(document).ready(function()
 {
      var my_div = $("#target");
      var div_top = my_div.offset().top;

      $(document).scroll(function()
        {
          if (div_top <= $(document).scrollTop())
            {
             alert("triggered");
            }
        });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="basic">
  <p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p>     <p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p>
</div>
<div id="target">
 <p> target </p>
</div>
<div id="basic">
  <p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p>   <p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to add half the screens height to your `$(document).scrollTop()`.  try to add `$(window).height() /2` to it

Comment: perfect! thats exactly what it needed